# How to convert .xls to .pdf via PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, xls

I was googling many hours but I haven't got solution yet.

I need to convert .xls file into .pdf file. How to do that? I have found this http://www.aspose.com/, but it seems, that it hasn't got PHP API, only .NET and JAVA.

Thanks for every advice...

Comment: Maybe use PHP EXCEL https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ to read it and TCPDF http://www.tcpdf.org/ to output it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Word doc, docx and Excel xls, xlsx to PDF with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538584/convert-word-doc-docx-and-excel-xls-xlsx-to-pdf-with-php)

Comment: Yes, I'm using PHP EXCEL to edit .xls, but TCPDF convertor always totally broke the .xls structure... In TCPDF documentation I even didn't find any function to convert .xls to .pdf...

Comment: PHPExcel provides a PDF Writer, which can be used as a wrapper for  tcPDF, mPDF or DomPDF as an actual PDF rendering engine... these three different engines provide different quality of output, but IMO tcPDF is the worst

Answer (score 6):

[PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) will do it directly (read XLS, output PDF), although the results are not very pretty.

A better solution might be to use PHPExcel to read the XLS file, render it to HTML in your code & style it the way you like it, then use an HTML->PDF converter like [DOMPDF](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) (that's the only one I've tried; there are others) to convert to PDF.

Or, if you want to skip the HTML step, render it directly to PDF using one of the PHP PDF libraries out there - my personal favourite is [FPDF](http://fpdf.org/).

Comment: Yes thanks, but how can I connect PHPEXCEL with FPDF? How can I edit this lines $rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_TCPDF;
$rendererLibrary = 'fpdf';
$rendererLibraryPath = 'fpdf/' . $rendererLibrary;?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean use FDPF as the renderer for PHPExcel; I meant load your XLS file, walk through the cells (in whatever way you want), and use FPDF to build the PDF document from scratch. A lot of work, I know, but FPDF makes it very easy to build a PDF document.

Answer (score 3):

use headless libreoffice and a shell command
`shell_exec('C:\wamp64\www\phpexcel\lo\App\libreoffice\program\soffice.exe --headless --convert-to pdf:calc_pdf_Export --outdir C:\wamp64\www\phpexcel\o C:\wamp64\www\phpexcel\new.xlsx');`

Comment: This works like a charm in Ubuntu -- provided you need to correct syntax for linux. Adding the exact command in below as answer to this for someone who is looking the same.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who is looking to do this in Ubuntu/linux using php -

Ubuntu comes with libre office installed default. Anyone can use the shell command to use the headless libre office for this.

```
shell_exec('/usr/bin/libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf:calc_pdf_Export --outdir /var/www/html/XlsToPdf/public_html/src/var/output /var/www/html/XlsToPdf/public_html/src/var/source/company-a.xlsx');
```

Hope it helps a others like me.