# codeigniter convert excel file to pdf

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, pdf

I want to ask how can I convert excel to pdf?

I want to put 5 excel files and after I click upload in convert to 1 pdf?

for now I use in this code:

```
    /**
 * Example: DOMPDF 
 *
 * Documentation: 
 * http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Usage
 *
 */
public function index() {   
    // Load all views as normal
    $this->load->view('test');
    // Get output html
    $html = $this->output->get_output();

    // Load library
    $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');

    // Convert to PDF
    $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
    $this->dompdf->render();
    $this->dompdf->stream("welcome.pdf");

}
```

the library:

class Dompdf_gen {

```
public function __construct() {

    require_once APPPATH.'third_party/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';

    $pdf = new DOMPDF();

    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->dompdf = $pdf;

}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate, this answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223491/how-to-convert-xls-to-pdf-via-php

Comment: i see the post But I do not understand about me code i i upload file excel and after i do open file and take the data from the excel and put in the pdf Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of things , you have to dump all excel to php array or var , after that you can create pdf as you want , this is simple php script for convert excel to pdf , you can use it and convert it to subclass of codeigniter as well

please check this url

[PHP read excel file](http://www.techchattr.com/how-to-read-excel-files-with-php)

when you use that class your excel data will be with you so you can use another class for pdf and this class  will help you

[codeigniter create PDF file](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/PDF-generation-using-dompdf)

hopeful this is helpful for you .

Comment: I do not understand the problem. like in this code:

    $this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));
    // page info here, db calls, etc.
    $html = $this->load->view('home', $data, true);
    pdf_create($html, 'filename')
    or
    $data = pdf_create($html, '', false);
    write_file('name', $data);
how i put after i upload excel file and cover it to pdf? this function is only for HTML

Comment: Hello , First of thing , convert your data from excel to php array or any data storage variable or array or class whatever , then use pdf class to create a pdf file , pass that data you got from excel to pdf class

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the problem.
like in this code:

```
    $this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));
    // page info here, db calls, etc.
    $html = $this->load->view('home', $data, true);
    pdf_create($html, 'filename')
    or
    $data = pdf_create($html, '', false);
    write_file('name', $data);
```

how i put after i upload excel file and cover it to pdf?
this function is only for HTML