# Path issues for render libraries in phpExcel for PDF

Tags: php, pdf, doc

I was searching and working many hours but I haven't got solution yet.

```
 I need to convert .xls, .xlx , and .txt file into .pdf file. How to do that? I hasn't got PHP API,
    I need to use only core PHP on localhost and not use any framework.
```

Thanks for every advice...

Comment: So what is your actual problem with PHPExcel? Have you read the documentation? Have you looked at the examples? Have you written any code?

Comment: refer below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538584/convert-word-doc-docx-and-excel-xls-xlsx-to-pdf-with-php