# how to convert word file to pdf file using php in codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am looking for a way to convert Word files to PDF using PHP.

The reason for this, is I need to be able to upload word  files of various formats .I want to convert those files to pdf in php.

I am using codeigniter Framework, so am hoping that someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

sorry for my english

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538584/convert-word-doc-docx-and-excel-xls-xlsx-to-pdf-with-php

Comment: I think this is outside the scope of CodeIgniter, but there are many ways to do it in general PHP, see the comment by @SNAG

Answer (score 0):

one of the best PHP word library is https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

you can modify any word documents from php and save them as pdf or any document format you want.

you just need to copy paste phpword in the libraries folder and use it as a library.