# Convert word doc file to PDF while uploading word Doc in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, ms-word

I have an issue i want to save my word file in PDF format while I am uploading.
How It is possible in PHP?

Comment: Welcome. This question is WAY to broad! Please read [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

While uploading file you cannot convert file because after fragment conversion its not possible to join another converted file.
The conversion techniques like OCR. How they can be applied to fragment. As fragment not having any extension. :-D
There may be many other reasons also. All above is my just guess.

BTW follow the link for convert...

```
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538584/convert-word-doc-docx-and-excel-xls-xlsx-to-pdf-with-php
```