# how to convert word file into image in php

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have been working for a few days, now, to convert from one image format to another,  such as:

from jpg -> png 
cropping an image

and the convert the document as follows:

pdf->tiff

I have done all this using Imagemagick, which supports all these conversions. But there is no support for 
MS Word (Doc/Docx) in Imagemagick. Does any one know how could it be done with php, because I have been searching a lot. Can anyone guide me how to do that or point me to any link / source of learning, which could guide me through it.
Regards,
Aqib awan

Comment: A document rendered object to a image file is a bit trickier than just jpg to png. You'll need some specific library to read the PDF and recreate it in tiff. ie. you could try http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Word doc, docx and Excel xls, xlsx to PDF with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538584/convert-word-doc-docx-and-excel-xls-xlsx-to-pdf-with-php)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to convert word document to image with php. You need to install PHPword to read the document files, then TCPDF to convert it to PDF , then Use Imagick to convert PDF to Image... It Works.