# Conversion of a doc file to PDF using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to know how to convert document file to pdf using php or codeigniter.
If anyone have any idea about the same please let me know.

Comment: Maybe start here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538584/convert-word-doc-docx-and-excel-xls-xlsx-to-pdf-with-php.

Answer (score 0):

To complete this, I would recommend two libraries. The first (I have not used), as Word documents are not plaintext, you will need to be able to read the Word doc. For this, try [PHPWord](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=phpword). This appears to have been used in other projects for the purpose of reading Word docs (and creating them).

Secondly, converting to PDF use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/), this library I have a lot of experience. It's been around a long time so there is some great examples and documentation. It doesn't take long to figure out but does require a bit of playing around to get the PDF doc looking exactly as you like. If you need any additional info using this library, give me a shout. But both of these should help you. FPDF can also be very easily converted to a Codeigniter library. I used it in a CiBonfire application before.