# How can I convert any file like .docx,xslx,img,txt to PDF preview using php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, pdf

I need to convert any file to PDF Preview if I click the document link in a table:
[Table Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuimd.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a PDF document to a preview image in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php)

Comment: Also check out: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php/

Comment: How did this get 3 upvotes?

Answer (score -3):

This code only for image to pdf convert.
If you have ImageMagick installed and `exec` permissions,

```
exec("convert foo.jpeg foo.pdf");
```

Below link for convert Word doc, docx and Excel xls, xlsx to PDF with PHP

[Convert Word doc, docx and Excel xls, xlsx to PDF with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538584/convert-word-doc-docx-and-excel-xls-xlsx-to-pdf-with-php)