# Convert doc and docx to images

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

I want to convert word documents into images.
Each page in word document will be converted into images.
I found following example and it converts ppt file into image.
I found word to image convertor script in php but it is not working , I am getting no output after executing page.
I also tried phpword to convert word file to pdf and then get images by using imagick  but in the phpword i didn't get images(inside word file) data. i get only text in the coverted pdf file. 
I tried so many ways but didn't get any solution.
Anyone can help me to found any way or solution?

```
$word = new COM("word.application") or die("ERROR: Unable to instantiate Word");
echo "Loaded Word, version {$word->Version}";
$word->Visible = 1;
$FilePath = "C:\\\\";
$DocFilename = "Sample.docx";
$stat = $word->Documents->Open(realpath("$DocFilename")) or die ("ERROR: Could not open Word Doc");
$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs("$FilePath", 17);
$word->Documents[1]->Close();
```

Comment: this question is already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538584/convert-word-doc-docx-and-excel-xls-xlsx-to-pdf-with-php

Comment: i need images of each page of the word file?

Comment: Do you see any errors while executing your script? You also need to remove doublequotes from variables, "$DocFilename" for example.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: <b>Source:</b> Microsoft Word<br/><b>Description:</b> The file appears to be corrupted. in D:\wamp64\www\Projects\sbaski.com\php_ppt_to_mail\php_ppt_to_mail.php on line 14
( ! ) com_exception: <b>Source:</b> Microsoft Word<br/><b>Description:</b> The file appears to be corrupted. in D:\wamp64\www\Projects\sbaski.com\php_ppt_to_mail\php_ppt_to_mail.php on line 14

Comment: Did you try another file?

Comment: Yes i tried anthor docx file which is already in same folder where the script is working

Comment: One would assume the error is on the line that tries to open the document? If yes, can the document be opened in Word when you try as a user, or does the error message also display?

Comment: Yes but how can i get images of each page with the help of php script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i am using libreOffice on the live server for convert doc , docx , ppt , pptx to pdf and then use of imagick to get my images.